# How to get context from HTML by tag with javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to get context out of news websites by tag. 
For example if I choose a news website like cnn, I load it on my website like this:

```
<object data="http://edition.cnn.com/" type="text/html" width="1400" height="700"> 
<embed src="http://edition.cnn.com/"></embed> 
Error: Embedded data could not be displayed. </object>
```

And then I choose an article and I need to get the content of the article.
When I open the source I see that I need to get the context from tag  until the last cnn_storypgraphtxt cnn_storypgraph tag (at least in cnn website).
I know that in PHP i can get information by tag name like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$p=$doc->getElementById('tag1')->getElementsByTagName('tag2')->item(0);
echo $p->nodeValue;
```

But this works only if tag1 keeps tag2 inside. 
In news websites it's hard to find an open tag which includes other tags, so I cannot use this.
What I want to know, whether it is possible to get the article in some way either in php or javascript and some guidance on how I could achieve this?
Any suggestions or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: most half-decent new sites have an RSS feed for doing this kind of stuff. CNN, BBC, you name it: they all have rss feeds. Still: writing a crawler isn't too difficult and there are many out there already. Use those as a reference, and try something. If you're stuck doing that, then post the specific problem here, and we'll try our best to help

Comment: You could use the fantastics [Symfony DomCrawler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html)+[Symfony CSS Selector](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/css_selector.html) components to retrieve any content from the CNN webpage

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I will try to do that! : )